# Converting String elements from an array to as values into an integer Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

I'm not allowed to use methods from any class except String and IO Class

So my code snippet is:

```
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    String[] elements = line.split(",");
    // Array could be too big if there are multiple occurances of
    // the same number
    // Array length + 1 because I can't use the 0 and with a input line of
    // 1,2,3 for example would be the length 3 but I would have the
    // numbers 0,1,2 in the Array as my index.
    String[][] placeholderMatrix = new String[elements.length+1][elements.length+1];
    for(int i = 0; i < elements.length-1; i++){
        placeholderMatrix[(int)elements[i]][(int)elements[i+1]] = 1;
    }
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

In the File I'm getting are only numbers like that: 1,2,3,4,5,8,7,4
So in my splitted String Array are only Numbers but now if I want to use them as my index for my Matrix(placeholderMatrix)

My problem is in my for loop where I want to use them as my Index I can't use them because it is a String Array. Normally I would use Integer.parseInt but I'm not allowed to :/
Any ideas on how I can implement them as my Index? and any Idea how I can get the perfect length of my Matrix? Because If I get the following numbers: 1,2,2,2,3 My Matrix should only have the numbers:

```
0 1 2 3
1
2
3
```

But if I'm using elements.length+1 for the length of my Matrix I would get the numbers 0 1 2 3 4 5

Hope you could understand my problem. Sorry for my bad english and Thanks in advance.

Edit: SO i got another problem with that. If I implement the method(parseInt) of Dici and am using it in the line "placeholderMatrix[parse(elements[i])][parse(elements[i+1])] = 1;" I'm getting the error ArrayOutOfBounce because my defined Array is just the length of my splitted String Array elements. But if I define it with Integer.MAX_VALUE as my length I get a memory error because it is too big. Any ideas?

Edit2: My Task:
I have to take a row of Numbers seperated by ",". (I will split it with the String split method to get only the numbers) Now I have to create a Matrix(2 dimensional Array) and look for the number at the index i of my new String Array and the number at the index i + 1 and have to take the first Number as my column and th second as my row (or vice versa) and implement at that point a 1. Now are my Numbers I will get from 1 to Integer.MAX_VALUE so I would have to create such a big Matrix but this isn't possible because I get the MemoryError.

Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
    at Test.main(Test.java:29)

To understand what I have to do: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjazenzmatrix the image at the right but for numbers from  to Integer.MAX_VALUE so my 2D Array has to be defined with the length of Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Edit:

So Dici asked for an example:

My Sequence could be: 1,2,5,4
So my Matrix should be:

[image: sample matrix]

Hope this is what you wanted Dici
But the numbers I can get from the sequence are 1 to Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: Your are looking for a manual way to do `Integer.parseInt`?

Comment: well I think that would solve the problem

Comment: Maybe you could use the fact that `15` is `10 * 1 + 5`. Another possibility if you only have values in [0-9] is to use char subtraction (ie. char value - '0')

Comment: my Values are [1;Integer.MAX_VALUE]

Comment: First I also thought about a char array but this will "explode" if I'm getting a big line with high numbers

Comment: I can see that your 2D array is declared inside the while loop. is that really right? for each line you need a 2d array?!

Comment: yes I need for every line a new 2D Array. It is declared in my task

Comment: Why should you have some rows and cols for nodes that do not exist in the graph (in this example, 3 never appears in the sequence but appears in the matrix) ? If you do it this ways, you will never be able to handle the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` sequence. I will propose you something after I eat :D

Comment: thanks^^ yeah but my problem is I could get a sequence with 1,2,3,4,5,6,4,8,7,5,6,9,(all numbers until Integer.MAX_VALUE) and it would be filled everywhere in each row and col but it would be too big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For converting strings to integers, you can simply implement your own integer parser, it is not complicated. You can start with this and improve it if needed.

```
public int parseInt(String s) { 
    int n   = 0;
    int pow = 1;
    for (int i=s.length() - 1 ; i>=0 ; i--) {
       String si = String.valueOf(s.charAt(i);

       if (si.matches("[0-9]")) {
           n   += pow*(s.charAt(i) - '0');
           pow *= 10;
       } else if (si.matches("+|-") && i == 0) 
           n   *= s.charAt(i) == '+' ? 1 : -1;
         else 
           throw new NumberFormatException();        
    }
    return n;
}
```

Then, I'll handle the second part of your problem. If `Integer.MAX_VALuE` is one of your input values, you cannot possibly allocate an `Integer.MAX_VALUE x Integer.MAX_VALUE` matrix. What you need to do is assign contiguous ids to your input values and record the ids in a map so that you can access easily the index of the matrix corresponding to one node value. Here is an example to get you to understand :

```
public void someMethod() {
    int id = 0;
    Map<Integer,Integer> idMap = new HashMap<>();
    String[] split = reader.readLine().split(",");
    int   [] nodes = new int[split.length];

    for (int i=0 ; i<nodes.length ; i++) {
        nodes[i] = parseInt(split[i]);
        if (!idMap.containsKey(nodes[i])) 
            idMap.put(nodes[i],id++);
    }

    // the map is now constructed, it should probably be stored in an attribute

    int[][] placeholderMatrix = new int[nodes.length][nodes.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
        if (i > 0)              placeholderMatrix[idMap.get(nodes[i])][idMap.get(nodes[i-1])] = 1;
        if (i < nodes.length-1) placeholderMatrix[idMap.get(nodes[i])][idMap.get(nodes[i+1])] = 1;
    }
}
```

There are other ways to do it, let me know if this solution is ok

Comment: My Values are from [1;Integer.MAX_VALUE];

Comment: So what ? This code return the correct value as long as s represents a valid int.

Comment: it does? I was confused of your if line with checking if the string matches [0-9]
Well charAt is checking if the number at the Index i is [0-9]?

Comment: Well I have not tested it but it should be ok, tell me if there is any problem. This line simply checks the character is a digit. Usually I would have used `Character.isDigit` but apparently you don't have the right to use this

Comment: SO i got another problem with that. If I implement your method and am using it in the line "placeholderMatrix[parse(elements[i])][parse(elements[i+1])] = 1;"
I'm getting the error ArrayOutOfBounce because my defined Array is just the length of my splitted String Array elements. But if I define it with Integer.MAX_VALUE as my length I get a memory error because it is too big. Any ideas?

Comment: What ? Your question is unclear but it seems it has nothing to do with my code, you are only accessing an element of an array that does not exist

Comment: Well the code is like it was before. The other code I got is the code from my professor which is letting me read from a file.
All i changed now is that I expanded my placeholderMatrix to the length Integer.MAX_VALUE: placeholderMatrix[Integer.MAX_VALUE][Integer.MAX_VALUE] because the numbers I'm getting are from the whole Integer numbers. So I need a 2 dimensional Array which can show them. or am I wrong? I'll add my Task I have to do in my main post

Comment: Do you realize how much memory you would need to allocate such a matrix ? `Integer.MAX_VALUE` equals `2^32` and let's assume your strings are all coded on 1 byte (single character), then you need `2^64` bytes, which is roughly 1 million times the capacity of an average hard disk for a PC. No way you could allocate such a huge matrix in your RAM...

Comment: Yeah I know that this is huge but I don't know how to solve it. I could send you the task so you can fully read the 2,5 pages but it is in german :/ http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjazenzmatrix look at the image at the right maybe this will help you (I get a sequence of numbers and have to make a graph like the one on the left side of the image with the element with the index i is connected to the element with the index i+1) and if a Number in my sequence is Integer.MAX_VALUE I have to implement it in my 2D Array

Comment: An adjacency matrix is N x N where N is the number of nodes. `Integer.MAX_VALUE` being one of these nodes does not mean there are `Integer.MAX_VALUE` nodes. I had not seen that part of your problem (because you did not really talk about it) and I am going to edit my answer to handle it

Comment: Could you provide us a sample file with the expected output ? I think I can code this in a few lines if you do so

Comment: I posted one in the main post

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
String keyword = "1,2,3,4,5,8,7,4";//input line from file
  String replacedKeyword = keyword.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");//except numbers replace all. Assuming one digit numbers only.
  String[][] placeholderMatrix = new String[replacedKeyword.length()+1][replacedKeyword.length()+1];
  char keys[] = replacedKeyword.toCharArray();
  for (int i = 0; i<keys.length - 1;  i++) {
    placeholderMatrix[keys[i] - '0'][keys[i + 1] -'0'] = "1";
  }
```

Comment: Works, but not a reusable solution

Comment: Absolutely but if you are just allowed to use String and IO routine and OP doesn't mention about two digit numbers, hence assumption.

Comment: at your second line I should be able to just use .split(","); because I know my numbers are only seperated by ","

Comment: Definately you could split not just by "," but by same regex but `keys[i] - '0'` is not going to work for two digit numbers unless you use some api like `Integer.parseInt`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really understand what you want exactly. but, if that going to help a simple method to convert String number to int:

```
int toInt(String number) {
    int num = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<number.length(); i++) {
        num = num*10 + (number.charAt(i)-'0');
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: well thanks but I already got such a method. My current problem is that my Matrix I try to create is too big for the memory

Comment: do you have empty cells?

Comment: yeah most likely but it could also be but if my professor is making a huge line with all cells being called then no lol.. You got an idea how to cut empty cells out?